# Eclipse GDB Launches - "No source available for "gdb[38].proc[42000].threadGroup[...)" "

Tags: eclipse, gdb

This has been bugging me forever. Perhaps someone else has run into it and found a solution.

**Target**

- Embedded MCU

**Setup**

- Eclipse CDT (8.3.0)
- Custom C/C++ Compiler (company internal, LLVM 3.1/etc, GNU ELF)
- Eclipse GDB Hardware Debugging Launch (8.3.0)

**Problem**

When I launch my debug-launch for this target, something goes crazy in the backend on gdb which you can see in *gdb traces console*. It looks like this (... is truncated linesb ):

(names changed to protect the innocent)

```
..360,743 2-environment-cd /home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj
360,743 2^done
360,743 (gdb) 
360,744 3-gdb-set breakpoint pending on
360,744 3^done
...
360,747 9source .gdbinit
...
360,748 ~"Reading symbols from /home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/Debug/myproj.elf..."
...
381,233 (gdb) 
381,233 58^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process",pid="42000"}]
...
381,516 65-data-disassemble --thread 1 -s 536883209 -e 536883241 -- 1
381,559 66-data-read-memory 2415919152 x 1 1 4
381,568 65^done,asm_insns=[src_and_asm_line={line="68",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/\
foo.c",line_asm_insn=[{address="0x2000300e",func-name="foo_initialize",offset="16",inst="call   0x20\
00409b <memset$fastcc>"},{address="0x20003013",func-name="foo_initialize",offset="21",inst="mov    $\
0x10,%eax"},{address="0x20003018",func-name="foo_initialize",offset="26",inst="xor    %edx,%edx"},{a\
ddress="0x2000301a",func-name="foo_initialize",offset="28",inst="mov    $0x60000210,%ecx"}]},src_and\
_asm_line={line="69",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[{address="0x\
2000301f",func-name="foo_initialize",offset="33",inst="call   0x2000409b <memset$fastcc>"}]},src_and\
_asm_line={line="70",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_a\
sm_line={line="71",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm\
_line={line="72",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_l\
ine={line="73",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_lin\
e={line="74",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line=\
{line="75",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line={l\
ine="76",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line={lin\
e="77",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line={line=\
"78",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line={line="7\
9",file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line={line="80"\
,file="/home/jmreina/myworkspace/myproj/myfcns/foo.c",line_asm_insn=[]},src_and_asm_line={line="81",f\
...
(FOUR-HUNDRED+ more lines of the same CRAPfrom myfcns/foo.c!)
...
```

Eclipse then shows in a blank editor:

[image]

```
No source available for "(gdb[38].proc[42000].threadGroup[i1],gdb[38].proc[42000].OSthread[1]).thread[1].frame[0]"
```

I *think* it shows this because that brick-of-crap above (**432 lines of it!)** took so dang long to load in the back-end, and I think the Eclipse-GDB plugins behind the launch did some sort of timeout.

I am very certain that foo.c sits *directly after main() in FLASH*. Thus GDB is calling the initialization here to fetch for the Disassembly View in Eclipse.

***Note that if the Disassembly View is closed (not minimized, closed), this doesn't happen.**

**Question**

1. Whhhhhy!
2. How do I even debug this? Maybe .debug_info is corrupt/missing for foo.c?

This annoys the crap out of me, >20 times/day, each and every day. How do I fix, or even understand it!?!?

Answer (score 1):

According to your topic, "No source available for ... ". One reason could be the incompatibility in version between *gdbserver* on target and *gdb* on host. You should check your toolchain if there is an target specific gdb available.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old thread but but maybe it helps some others.
Yesterday, I also had this error and it occured on debugging an XMC4500 board with DAVE and J-Link. Program upload using J-link also worked fine.

I reinstalled Eclipse IDE -> no change
updated J-Link -> no change
compiling worked fine
debugging other projects on another board worked fine

My solution was to run the J-link flashtool (e.g. JFlash.exe or JFlashLite.exe, you can find it in the installation directory of Segger J-Link), erase the total chip. After that the error was away.

Regards

Geri

Comment: interesting! Thank you for posting this up, but another magical JTAG solution that becomes so easy, once found. Thanks!